# SimpleDraweeView scale proportionally

Tags: android, resize, scale, fresco

I wan't to insert in my SimpleDraweeView with

```
 android:layout_width="50dp"
 android:layout_height=50dp
```

some picture, that may  be bigger than this dimensions. I want to resize picture proportionally, so for example picture with source dimension 117x81 should show like 50x34. What should I do to that the picture is not circumcised, but decreased proportionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set actualImageScaleType in you xml and choose centerInside option. Do not use android:scaleType since it does not have effect on Drawee.

Please take a look at other available options as well. 
[image]

Reference link: [Fresco Drawee Scaling](http://frescolib.org/docs/scaling.html)

Comment: Thank you! I saw this article, but i was trying to use android:scaleType :)

Comment: No problems @DimaStoyanov. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can doing that with is code:

```
simpleDraweeView.getHierarchy().setActualImageScaleType(ScalingUtils.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```